# Getting error "Invalid account" while trying to deploy smart contract to Goerli Testnet

Tags: solidity, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, smart-contract

Getting an error while I'm trying to deploy a smart contract to Goerli testnet.
The error:

```
Error HH8: There's one or more errors in your config file:

* Invalid account: #0 for network: goerli - private key too long, expected 32 bytes

To learn more about Hardhat's configuration, please go to https://hardhat.org/config/

For more info go to https://hardhat.org/HH8 or run Hardhat with --show-stack-traces
```

Here is my **hardhat.config.js** file:

```
/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */

require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");

const ALCHEMY_API_KEY = "API_KEY";
const GOERLI_PRIVATE_KEY = "PRV_KEY";
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.17",

  networks: {
    goerli: {
      url: `https://eth-goerli.alchemyapi.io/v2/${ALCHEMY_API_KEY}`,
      accounts: [GOERLI_PRIVATE_KEY],
    },
  },
};
```

I was on the same directory (The scripts directory). Also I copied the private key from Metamask of my Goerli account. I searched on google but found nothing helpful.

Comment: What is "PRV_KEY" here? I assume you are trying to import it from .env file. Is it so?

Comment: Actually I hard typed api & key. & Before post just replaced with API_KEY & PRV_KEY. @SolidityLearner

Comment: Make sure the private key is correct.
And once without the strings.

Comment: Or you can use .env file for it, that's how I always write code and it works every single time.

Answer (score 0):

After trying two days , I opened a new metamask and created a new account & by following the same private key copy method which I followed on my first metamask it worked perfectly, IDK what happend but it worked.